Is this a reliable chart to to use to begin diagnose car A/C problems?
I've gotten my hands dirty with a manifold gauge set and topped off my car's A/C refrigerant last week. After the recharge, I really brought down the temperature.
I'd like to do more with car A/Cs eg. maybe help a friend with his car's A/C in the future. I found this chart online and wonder if it's a reliable go-to guide for beginning to diagnose a car's A/C problem


No. Things to learn about vehicle ac systems, diagnosing, troubleshooting, repairs and acquiring tools and equipment. I liken vehicle ac systems similar to super or turbo charging. If you do not become completely familiar with super or turbo charging, things can go wrong quickly. The same applies to ac systems. Learning about refrigeration, chemicals, contamination, leaks, dye, uv blacklights, are some things to become an above average diyer. When you topped off your system, how do you know there wasn't a leak since all ac systems are considered sealed? Acceptable leakage; <3 grams per year.
